# How to update datagridview from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 forms: a `ProductSelectionForm` and `QuantityPriceForm`

The `ProductSelection` Form contains a datagridview with 3 columns (

- Product Name
- Quantity
- Price

I take the `Quantity` and `price` from the `getQuantityPrice` form which contains 2 textboxes for the said values.

so far I have worked on this code:

`Productselection Form`:

```
 public void getQuanPrice() // call getQuantityPrice form
    {
       QuantityPriceForm obj = new QuantityPriceForm(this);
        obj.ShowDialog();
    }
```

`getQuantityPrice Form`:

```
ProductSelection form1; // public initialization

public QuantityPriceForm(ProductSelection form_1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = form_1;
    }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult saveData = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the data?",
      "Save Data",
      MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
      MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (saveData == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            form1.dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = quant;
            form1.dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = agreePrice;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

The data grid view does not update the quantity and price column in form 1. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, your Product Selection Form still has the DataGridView control `dgvProducts` set to Private (the default).

You could set it to public so your child form could access it, but that is poor style.

Instead, pass parameters to your child form and read them back on success:

Product Selection Form:

```
 public void getQuanPrice() // call getQuantityPrice form
 {
    QuantityPriceForm obj = new QuantityPriceForm(this);
    obj.quant = (int)dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value;
    obj.agreePrice = (double)dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
    if (obj.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value = obj.quant;
      dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value = obj.agreePrice;
    }
 }
```

Now, on your getQuantityPrice Form, you need to create those two Public Properties:

```
// ProductSelection form1; (you don't need this)

public QuantityPriceForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public int quant {
  get { return (int)txtQuantity.Text; }
  set { txtQuantity.Text = value.ToString(); }
}

public int agreePrice {
  get { return (double)txtAgreePrice.Text; }
  set { txtAgreePrice.Text = value.ToString(); }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DialogResult saveData = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the data?",
    "Save Data",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Question);

  if (saveData == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    this.DialogResult = saveData;
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, for me or him? :) Actually, he's probably in a class, and this was his homework assignment.